# How to stop timer tick

Tags: python, pygame

In my code, I have a timer called timer. I started 
it somewhere in the game by doing timer.tick(). I was wondering if there is any kind of command that can stop the timer from recording time anymore and just stop. Because if I just set it to zero it keeps going, which I have tried. Is there a command like timer.stop(). I have tried many things such as looking online for this, and settings it to zero, etc..

Thank you
EDIT_______________________

This is the variables before main loop

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60
timer = pygame.time.Clock()
storydelay = 5000
time_count = 0
```

After main loop

```
if story:

    timer.tick()
    time_count += timer.get_time()

    if time_count < storydelay:
        mainmenu = False
        screen.blit(black_image,zero_position)
    if time_count > storydelay:
        mainmenu = True
```

Basically what I want to do is when the time_count > storydelay, the timer should stop, so I can recall it back some other time

Comment: Well I just need one command but ok just a sec

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: So just set the `timer = 0`, and `time_count = 0` after your last if statement.

Comment: Just in case you didn't see my comment below, you don't need the second `pygame.time.Clock` just use the `clock` instead of `timer` (but don't call `clock.tick(FPS)` twice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `timer.get_time()` returns the time from the last call to `timer.tick()`, all you have to do is set the `timer_count` back to 0 and `call timer.tick()` to reset everything.

Here is an example:

```
import pygame

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60
timer = pygame.time.Clock()
storydelay = 5000
time_count = 0

story = True
timer.tick()

while story:
    time_count += timer.tick()
    if time_count < storydelay:
        pass
    if time_count > storydelay:
        time_count = 0
        print "story done"
        story = False
    clock.tick(FPS)

main_menu = True
timer.tick()

while main_menu:
    time_count += timer.tick()
    if time_count > 3000:
        time_count = 0
        print "menu done"
        main_menu = False
    clock.tick(FPS)

print "done"
```

As you can see, before each loop if started; `timer.tick()` is called and when each loop is closed `time_count` is reset

Hope this helps.

Comment: You don't need the second `Clock`.

Comment: True, I was debating whether to remove it or keep it in because it follows the OP's code a little more closely

Comment: Yeah, that comment was actually more directed @abc1234. Do OPs get notified about comments to answers?

Comment: Thank you very much